# Theorem: Sequence is convergent if an only if that is Cauchy's sequence

Tags: calculus

I have a problem with proof, I can prove in a one way

$$ \epsilon > 0\\|a_n- a| < \epsilon/2\\|a_m- a_n| = |(a_m- a) - (a_n- a)| \leq |a_m- a| + |a_n- a| < \epsilon $$

I dont know in a other way.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Here are some facts that should let you prove that Cauchy sequences are convergent. (If you haven't proved these or seen them proved, it's a good exercise to do so.)

- Every sequence of real numbers has a monotone (non-decreasing or non-increasing) subsequence.
- Subsequences of Cauchy sequences are again Cauchy.
- Cauchy sequences are bounded.
- Bounded monotone sequences are convergent.
- A Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence is itself convergent.